# How do the fees for taproot transactions compare to P2WPKH?

Tags: transaction-fees, taproot, p2wpkh, p2tr

How would the most basic taproot transactions (not involving scripts) compare to P2WPKH transactions in terms of vbytes or fees?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/119301/5406

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taproot inputs are smaller but outputs are larger. Specifically, P2WPKH (Native SegWit) inputs and outputs take 68 and 31 vbytes in a transaction, respectively, while P2TR (Taproot) inputs and outputs take 57.5 and 43 vbytes, respectively. In terms of fees this makes Taproot transactions about 1.5% more expensive when you don't use multisig or scripting.

Source: https://bitcoinops.org/en/tools/calc-size/

Comment: Note that the cost for the output is paid by the sender, but the recipient saves the cost on the smaller input; the recipient picks the address they'd like to get paid to, though. :)