# Would exchanges save block space by defaulting deposit addresses to P2TR?

Tags: exchanges, p2tr, transaction-weight

If inputs weigh less in P2TR than other address types, and exchanges conduct big batch transactions for withdrawals, is there a significant efficiency gain in block space they consume if most of their transactions eventually become P2TR?

Comment: Related: [Is there an economic incentive to switch from P2WPKH to P2TR?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/119301/121614)

Comment: Yeah, I think that your question is covered in the topic that Vojtěch mentioned. If you agree, please vote to close as a duplicate. Otherwise, please edit your question to expand on how your question differs from the linked topic.

Comment: I think the linked topic covers it well. Thank you, I’ll vote to close

Comment: Murch, I need more reputation before I can vote to close. Can you close this?